# Mongoose ODM, change variables before saving

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, odm

I want to create a model layer with Mongoose for my user documents, which does:

1. validation (unique, length)
2. canonicalisation (username and email are converted to lowercase to check uniqueness)
3. salt generation
4. password hashing
5. (logging)

All of these actions are required to be executed before persisting to the db. Fortunately mongoose supports validation, plugins and middleware.

The bad thing is that I cannot find any good material on the subject.
The official docs on mongoosejs.com are too short...

Does anyone have an example about pre actions with Mongoose (or a complete plugin which does all, if it exists)?

Regards

Comment: I thought the documentation on mongoosejs.com was pretty clear in this area.  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: the validation sector is clear but not how to prepare the object before some persistment. I think the Schema.pre('save', callback); function could be it but the full example is missing also I don't know how to access the attributes of the object in the pre function

Comment: You access the attributes of the document via `this` in your middleware function.

Comment: Could you copy this in an answer so I can mark the question answered :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your `Schema.pre('save', callback)` function, `this` is the document being saved, and modifications made to it before calling `next()` alter what's saved.

Answer (score 30):

Another option is to use Getters. Here's an example from the website:

```
function toLower (v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
}

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, set: toLower } 
});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the only option if the value that you're passing is not the same type that is defined in the schema for the specified property. E. g. You have an `amount` property that is of type `number` but the value that you pass in for processing is a `string`.

Answer (score 17):

```
var db = require('mongoose');
var schema = new db.Schema({
  foo:     { type: String }
});

schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.foo = 'bar';

  next();
});

db.model('Thing', schema);
```

Comment: it could be noted, that pre for 'save' does not fire on update. use 'update' instead

Comment: @sasha can you explain what you mean

Comment: @DipanshuMahla It's been a bit and I'm currently not to deep into mongoose tbh, but what I meant was probably that the schema.pre('save') function does not fire (or doesn't get executed), when data gets updated. It might only fire when new data is inserted. So when you want to have updates covered via schema.pre(), you should use 'update'